# Pass data to next screen php | wordpress | fancy box

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, fancybox

I'm new to web and working on WordPress site that have to play a video in fancy box. RIght now i'm hardcoding the URL in my video.php file. However i want to pass it from a different screen with all the data.

My code is as:

**Main Screen (content.php)**

```
    jQuery.fancybox({
        'width'             : '100%',
        'height'            : '100%',
        'autoScale'         : true,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'iframe',
        'href'              : 'video.php'
    });
```

Code of **video.php** file is as:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var source = getVideoSource(21851);
var el = jQuery('video');
jQuery('video').attr('src',source);
el.onloadedmetadata = e => {
hidden_source.srcObject = vid.captureStream ? vid.captureStream() : vid.mozCaptureStream();
  }
});

function getVideoSource(id){
    return 'https:baseURL/v2/hls/' + id+'.m3u8';
}

</script>

<div class="video-js-box">

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="100%" height="100%" controls="controls" preload="auto" autoplay>

  <source type='application/vnd.apple.mpegurl' />

  </video>
</div>
```

How can i pass video id (e.g.21851) to video.php file. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Simply create links like this - video.php?id=21851 - and then use $_GET to retrieve id.

Comment: @Janis, thankyou so much. Can you kindly explain a bit more with coding example. I'm new with very less knowledge of web. 
i know get, and understood the URL thing, but don't know how to retrieve it in video.php file. Please help.

Comment: Then start with basics, read some PHP tutorials and the manual is very useful, too  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php